# JSP and Servlet parsing Parameter

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Let's say I got a delete Button on my jsp site which has the following code:

```
<a href="deleteMovie?movieID=${movie.movieID}">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicontrash" aria-hidden="true"></span> Delete </button></a>
```

As we can see whenever I click my Delete Button it is forwarding to the site

> "deleteMovie?movieID=${movie.movieID}"

I also got a servlet which is mapped to "/deleteMovie" so the servlet is called.
Inside the servlet i have the following code:

```
String movieID = request.getParameter("movieID");
```

How can you explain me that whatever I write behind the equals sign in the href value, that this specific text is returned under the String movieID?
For example if I would write:

```
<a href="deleteMovie?movieID=Foo">
```

Then the String movieID would contain "Foo".
But why? Why is it parsing the movieID out of the href?

Comment: What exactly is unexpected about it? What would you prefer/expect to happen?

Comment: @4castle I am new to Java Server Pages so its confusing for me.. I am absolutely fine when getting back the values from input forms where you can set the name of the input form and in the servlet you can access it by its name...but this is rather confusing? Let's say I want to add another value here to the request, how could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a GET request, you can give parameters to a request by using a query string. A query string is a `?` followed by name-value pairs such as `movieID=Foo`. In this case, the value of `movieID` is `Foo`. If you want more than one name-value pair, put an `&` between them.

When you submit a `form`, it creates these parameters for you. So if you were to submit this form:

```
<form method="GET" action="deleteMovie">
    <input type="hidden" name="movieID" value="Foo" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

It would generate a URL of `deleteMovie?movieID=Foo` and then send it off.

Comment: Thank you very much! The "&" was the thing I was looking for!
So I just learned something new, thank you!
So the only 2 ways to pass parameters from a jsp to another or to a servlet is by using forms which are doing the work for you, or passing it via the href?

Comment: There is another way. You should look up how to use a session! It sounds like it is exactly what you want. :D It similarly stores name-value pairs, but they are only accessible server-side and from all requests coming from the same user (within a certain amount of time). They are very easy to use too.

Comment: If you want some longer-term storage. Look up how to use a cookie.

Comment: Yeah I know what a session is and how to store objects under a name with .setAttribute(), but the thing is that you can only set such an attribute with a servlet and in my case I just used the servlet for deleting it!

Comment: In that case, the answer to your first comment is yes. Using a form or an href is the only way to move data from the client to the server. Although I think Java uses cookies in an interesting way which can cross that gap also.

Comment: ok that was the answer I was waiting for :D Thank you for your help :) Okay I will take a look on that too!

Answer (score 1):

well there is nothing confusing in the code well if this is your url

```
<a href="submitvalues?parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2">
```

then `parametes1 and parameter2 are parameter names` and values are assigned to them with `=` sign parameters are seperarted by a `& sign`.
on the `servlet side` if you are providing the `correct parameter name` 
then you can get these values

```
String param1 = request.getParameter("parameter1");
String param2 = request.getParameter("parameter2");
```

theres nothing confusing in that.